# User registration profiles - not shown in user detail

Tags: 7, users

I'm using the [multi step registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module to have different steps in my register form. I have multiple Profile2 types for my user registration.

The user registration is shown in different steps, each step is a profile type. This all works fine. I can also edit a user with the wizard. The problem is when I want to see the user details I only see one profile of the user.

I've checked the permissions about profile but they are correct. Also checked manage display but nothing is hidden. What could be the problem of this?

Also tried to alter the function [hook_profile2_view_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.api.php/function/hook_profile2_view_alter/7)

```
function other_profile2_view_alter($build) {
    dump($build);
}
```

But the dump shows that only fields of one profile are shown.

**UPDATE:**

This is the overview of my Profile types (these are all the steps shown in my user registration):

[image]

And this is when you click on edit of a profile:

[image]

As you can see the step is shown in the user registration.

Comment: How are you creating the new profiles?  Can you post the code?

Comment: Updated my topic .